# Could not set unknown property 'nav_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin, navigation

I was trying to add Navigation dependencies to utilize the Navigation graph in my project and android studio threw this error.

This is my project Gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha01" //extra property, used like variables
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files

        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

As you can see I added both a $nav_version dependency and the nav_version variable. But, android studio throws a "Could not set unknown property 'nav_version' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler" error. I wonder if it has something to do with the Gradle version or my Kotlin version. I tried to clean and re-build my project but it didn't work. I was wondering if anyone has encountered something similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be part of app level build.gradle.

Something like

```
dependencies {
  def nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha01"

  // Kotlin
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"

  // Dynamic Feature Module Support
  implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:$nav_version"

  // Testing Navigation
  androidTestImplementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-testing:$nav_version"
}
```

& top/project level gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha01"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}
```

Or place it like ${nav_version}

```
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:${nav_version}"
```

Or

```
buildScript {
  ext {
    nav_version = "2.3.0-alpha01"
    kotlin_version = "1.3.50"
  }

    dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
            classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlin_version}"
            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files

            classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:${nav_version}"
    }
}
```

Reference
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: Thank you, I was confused on where the nav_version variable. I tried the last option you mentioned and that worked for me.

Comment: Cool. You can accept the answer if works for you as it helped others to refer the same